# Retrieve a list of users based on some conditions

Tags: wpdb

What am I doing wrong on this query? The main issue is the `var_dump` returns null. The query works fine in phpMyAdmin.

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT 
            u.ID AS id, 
            u.user_login AS name,
            AVG(b.star) AS rating, 
            COUNT(b.star) AS reviews,
            m.meta_value AS roles
        FROM
            wp_users AS u
                LEFT JOIN
            wp_usermeta AS m ON u.ID = m.user_id
                LEFT JOIN
            wp_bp_activity AS b ON u.ID = b.usercheck
        WHERE
            (m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND m.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%') 
        AND 
            (b.is_activated is null or b.is_activated = 1)
        GROUP BY u.ID
        ORDER BY reviews DESC
        LIMIT %d", $limit
    )
);
return var_dump($users);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with the `'%subscriber%'` part, inside the `wpdb::prepare()` method.

Use `'%%subscriber%%'` instead.

Otherwise `$limit` will match the `%s` part and the  `%d` part will be unmatched.